# How to post data from api stepzilla formwizard in react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created small application in reactjs. I have used Stepzilla formwizard form loading fine, but I want to form validation and form data post api call in this code how to implement validation and post data, I referred more reference but could not solve this issue could you please check my code please.

my code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import StepZilla from "react-stepzilla";
import Stepper from "@mui/material/Stepper";
import Step from "@mui/material/Step";
import StepLabel from "@material-ui/core/StepLabel";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import StepContent from "@mui/material/StepContent";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { Form, } from "react-bootstrap";
import validator from "validator";
import { Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";

const Accounts = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <section>
          <Form>
          <Row className="mb-3">
        <Form.Group
              as={Col}
              md="6" 
            >
              <Form.Label>Account Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="account-name" 
              />
            </Form.Group>
            
            </Row>
            </Form>
        </section>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
const Address = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <section>

          <Form>
            <Row className="mb-3">
        <Form.Group
              as={Col}
              md="12" 
            >
              <Form.Label>Region</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="region" 
              />
            </Form.Group>
            
            </Row>
            </Form>
        </section>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
const Rwood = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <section>

          <Form>
            <Row className="mb-3">
        <Form.Group
              as={Col}
              md="12" 
            >
              <Form.Label>KYC Docs</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="kycdocs" 
              />
            </Form.Group>
            
            </Row>
            </Form>
        </section>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
const Industry = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <section>

          <Form>
            <Row className="mb-3">
        <Form.Group
              as={Col}
              md="6" 
            >
              <Form.Label>Under Group</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="under-group" 
              />
            </Form.Group>
            
        <Form.Group
              as={Col}
              md="6" 
            >
              <Form.Label>Billing Street</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="b-street" 
              />
            </Form.Group>
            </Row>
            </Form>
        </section>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <section>

          <Form>
            <Row className="mb-3">
        <Form.Group
              as={Col}
              md="6" 
            >
              <Form.Label>Salutation</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="salutation" 
              />
            </Form.Group>
           <Row>
           </Form
        </section>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
const stepswizard =
  [
    { name: '1', component: <Accounts /> },
    { name: '2', component: <Address /> }, 
    { name: '3', component: <Rwood /> },
    { name: '4', component: <Industry /> },
    { name: '5', component: <Contact /> } 
  ]
export const AccordionWizardForm = () => {
  return (
    <div className='step-progress'>
      <h6>
        <StepZilla steps={stepswizard} />
      </h6>
    </div>
  );
}
```

could you please solve this issues

Comment: Its better to have a output of what you are getting, what is the expected output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Need validation and form data send to API